# Loading color values from pixel array

Tags: c++, bmp

I read this tutorial http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/Cpp/BitmapTutorial.html about bitmap and it really helped..I need to read color integer values from elements of  pixel array. How to do that?
Ok heres the code for putting data into rgb array

```
BYTE* ConvertBMPToRGBBuffer ( BYTE* Buffer, int width, int height )
{

if ( ( NULL == Buffer ) || ( width == 0 ) || ( height == 0 ) )
    return NULL;

// find the number of padding bytes

int padding = 0;
int scanlinebytes = width * 3;
while ( ( scanlinebytes + padding ) % 4 != 0 )     // DWORD = 4 bytes
    padding++;
// get the padded scanline width
int psw = scanlinebytes + padding;

// create new buffer
BYTE* newbuf = new BYTE[width*height*3];

// now we loop trough all bytes of the original buffer, 
// swap the R and B bytes and the scanlines
long bufpos = 0;   
long newpos = 0;
for ( int y = 0; y < height; y++ )
    for ( int x = 0; x < 3 * width; x+=3 )
    {
        newpos = y * 3 * width + x;     
        bufpos = ( height - y - 1 ) * psw + x;

        newbuf[newpos] = Buffer[bufpos + 2];       
        newbuf[newpos + 1] = Buffer[bufpos+1]; 
        newbuf[newpos + 2] = Buffer[bufpos];     
    }

return newbuf;
    }
```

Comment: Dude, if you want people to help you here on SO, you should provide code that you have so far and not expecting people to do all the work for you.

Comment: Don't you want to add tag `gdi`? Maybe provide some code, show some effort of yours, what you have tried... maybe you want to ask question that will be less abstract than *"How to do that?"*...

Comment: And what is your question now? How to get one value for red, green and blue?

Comment: yes that is the question but user1118321 answered it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your image is in RGB interleaved format. To get a pixel at (x,y), simply index the array at that location. It would be easiest if your buffer pointed to a structure type. Something like:

```
typedef struct RGBPixel {
    BYTE red;
    BYTE green;
    BYTE blue;
} RGBPixel;
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
RGBPixel* pixels = (RGBPixel*)newbuf;
```

To get a pixel at (x,y), you'd do this:

```
RGBPixel aPixel = pixels [ y * width + x ];
```